# Ag-grid - having expandable height cells causes rendering issues

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I have an Ionic/Angular project where I wish to use the Ag-grid as a (virtual) container for my potentially very large list of items. I am very new the the ag-grid, I have played a little in the past, but still relatively new to it

Ag-grid is the has come the closest by far to being able to do what I am trying to achieve.

Basically I have a list of items, where I wish to use an **Angular component** in each cell, and this component has an "expander", with a varying number of sub items.

To get a component in the grid, I followed [this excellent tutorial](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/easier-embedding-of-angular-ui-in-ag-grid-52db93b73884), which seemed to work perfectly.

It almost all works, but I find when I expand items down the list a bit (eg item position say 50), the UI starts to jump around, and not render properly. If you expand the first few, it is ok, it is only when you get down the list a bit I have problems.

I have a sample project [here on Github](https://github.com/pjc2007/aggrid-expander.git).

It looks like the following...

[image]

My setup of the grid is in `home.page.ts`, where I have the following gridOptions

```
        gridOptions: GridOptions = {  
            // Makes col take up full grid
            onGridSizeChanged: () => {
                this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            } ,
                    
            getRowHeight(params) {
                return params.data.getHeight();
            },

            getRowNodeId: function (data) {
                return data.equipment;
            },
        }
```

The `getRowHeight` above will call `ListItem.getHeight`, and you can see this returns the height based on whether or not is it expanded...

```
         public getHeight(): number {
            let height = 72;
            if (this.isOpen)
                height += (this.jobs.length - 1) * 40;
            
            return height;
        }
```

Also, when the expander is clicked the `refresh` function passed into the constructor is called.

```
        public setIsOpen(val: boolean) {
            this.isOpen = val;    
            this.refresh();
        }
```

And this call the following in the `home.page.ts` to try and refresh the grid cells..

```
    private refreshCells(): void {
        this.gridOptions.api.refreshCells({ force: true });
        this.gridOptions.api.resetRowHeights();
    }
```

And that's basically it.

It is close to working, ie click the initial items works, but when I scroll down, sometimes the view just does not refresh properly (sometimes it does, other times not).

Is this achievable, and if so, what can I do get get it to work better?

Comment: have you tried turning off row virtualisation by using this grid property rowBuffer=0, https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-dom-virtualisation/#row-virtualisation

Comment: The big thing I actually want is the virtualization, otherwise I could actually just use an ion-list. When I use any container that holds the whole dom this is all fine, but I need virtualization for possibly very large lists. I've tried others and all are not very good at all for what I want. The Ag-Grid comes very close, just this one issue